# tns build gives FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a code sharing angular 8 + nativescript 6 project.

When I perform a tns build it fails with the following trace. The standout line being FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.

```
tns build android
Preparing project...
Hash: 29a5dd937bd8e4ccc851
Version: webpack 4.30.0
Time: 33853ms
Built at: 07/31/2019 4:34:20 PM
              Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
               0.js   29.9 KiB        0  [emitted]
               1.js     24 KiB        1  [emitted]
               2.js   33.5 KiB        2  [emitted]
          bundle.js    235 KiB   bundle  [emitted]  bundle
       package.json  133 bytes           [emitted]
         runtime.js   15.5 KiB  runtime  [emitted]  runtime
tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes           [emitted]
          vendor.js   37.1 MiB   vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 450 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 481 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.css] 275 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 66 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 749 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 850 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/auth/auth.service.ts] 37 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/auth/firebase/firebase-auth.service.ts] 3.38 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/auth/helper/nav/nav-helper.service.ts] 776 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/auth/login/login.component.ts] 4.3 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/core/core.module.ts] 2.95 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.ts] 690 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/user-profile/user-profile.component.ts] 5.27 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 1.95 KiB {bundle} [built]
    + 837 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete.
nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare.
Project successfully prepared (android)
Configure firebase
Copy C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\App_Resources\Android\google-services.json to C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\platforms\android\app\google-services.json.
Building project...
Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
         Applying settings from C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\App_Resources\Android\settings.json
         + using andorid X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\nativescript_plugin_firebase.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\node_modules\nativescript-unit-test-runner\platforms\android\nativescript_unit_test_runner.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Robert\spynal\spynal-app\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6479BC6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF647997416 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF647997D90 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF647CB189E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF647CB17CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF647E97F94 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF647E8EF76 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF647E8D5CC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF647E96317 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF647E96396 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF647FC0637 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF64803D826 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
13: 000002F1F42DC5C1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk8u192-b12\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 134

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1
```

The webpack process appears to complete succesfully however the gradle build conks out just over halfway.

Researching I've found the --max-old-space-size options for node. I just don't know how to apply it to the gradle build process or if this is the actual problem. Any guidance is appreciated.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "spynal",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.spynal",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    }
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build-prod-ngsw": "\"ng build --prod && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy\"",
    "compile": "\"for lang in en; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --prod --base-href=/$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --i18n-locale=$lang; done\"",
    "coverage": "\"ng test --watch=false --code-coverage\"",
    "docs": "\"compodoc -p tsconfig.json\"",
    "i18n": "\"ng xi18n\"",
    "ng": "ng",
    "ngsw-config": "\"ngsw-config dist ngsw-config.json\"",
    "ngsw-copy": "\"cp ./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js dist/\"",
    "serve-docs": "\"compodoc -s -r 4300\"",
    "serve-prod-ngsw": "\"npm run build-prod-ngsw && http-server dist -p 8000\"",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "android": "tns run android --bundle",
    "ios": "tns run ios --bundle",
    "mobile": "tns run --bundle",
    "preview": "tns preview --bundle",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "bitmovin-player": "^8.10.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "dashjs": "^2.9.3",
    "firebase": "^6.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "generate-json": "^0.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "^8.0.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.2",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.7.0",
    "ng-momentum": "^0.0.24",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^1.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rx-player": "^3.13.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript-collections": "^1.3.2",
    "videogular2": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.2",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.6.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/cli": "^5.1.9",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.8",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-nativescript-launcher": "0.4.0",
    "karma-webpack": "4.0.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.0.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-schematics-for-storybook": "^0.2.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "rxjs-spy": "^7.5.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    "wait-for-expect": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.tns.json

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom",
            "es6",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "**/*.tns.ts",
        "**/*.android.ts",
        "**/*.ios.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.stories.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command for remove fatal error in node_modules.

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --baseHref=/baseUrl/ --prod=true
```